Reevalulation of privileges / trusted user level
Although we had a long period with only a low amount of trusted users, the site is continuing to grow. However, when a site grows out of beta and into maturity, there comes a time when the privilege level is re-evaluated. For cryptography this time has come now. That means that the trusted user status will only be reached at 40K of reputation.
The other privileges are also handled the same way: basically you need to reach double figures, similarly to how privileges are calculated on StackOverflow. Note that privileges are not separately stored but directly calculated from reputation. For more information please view this video [youtube]. The change should take place 3 to 5 days from this announcement.
Complaints against this change may go in the comment or answer boxes.

Yes, I really don't get it. Tor and us. Are you posting the correct links?

40k would be double what's needed on stackoverflow.

To anyone thinking this is a serious post: Click the video link.

3 to 5 days from the announcement, eh :-)

Three now, five is right out.

29th March here.

Yes, next are 30, 31 and 32.

Alright, as most of you will have figured out by now this is an April fools joke. As I have an appointment this evening I don't have the time to wait around.
Obviously there is no need for elevated rep levels for privileges, especially not on our site where the number of trusted users (rep. 20,000 and higher) is relatively low.
It is true that privileges can be lost whenever a user dips below a certain rep level. I found that out when putting out a large bounty on a meta site, so please beware of that.
Thanks go to kelalaka and Maeher for taking this seriously. Without you this joke would have fallen flat, as there was very little outrage. We are a sea of calm in the sometimes rocky StackExchange network; let's keep it that way.
